# How to update results when clicking backspace in UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I'm a beginner to Swift and Xcode. I have a `UITableview` with a list of items and a `UISearchBar`. I want the list to get filtered every time a letter is added or erased from the Textfield of the `UISearchBar`.

Everything works when typing in letters, but with the code that I have, I can't get the list to bring back some of the items when I erase some of the letters, until the text field is empty and the entire list is called.

```swift
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchBar.text?.count == 0 {
            loadListOfExercises()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
        else {
            listOfExercises = listOfExercises?.filter("nameOfExercise CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!).sorted(byKeyPath: "nameOfExercise", ascending: true)            
            self.listTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

This is the code that I have for loadListOfExercises()

```
func loadListOfExercises() {

        listOfExercises = realm.objects(ExerciseInList.self)

        self.listTableView.reloadData()

    }
```

Comment: What is the type of listOfExercises

Comment: I'm using a Realm database, and listOfExercises is of type Results<...>?

Comment: Please call self.listTableView.reloadData() when searchBar.text?.count == 0 it will solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code to identify backspace

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {        
    if searchBar.text?.count == 0 {
        loadListOfExercises()
        self.listTableView.reloadData()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }else {
        listOfExercises = listOfExercises?.filter("nameOfExercise CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!).sorted(byKeyPath: "nameOfExercise", ascending: true)
        self.listTableView.reloadData()
    }

    if let char = searchText.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")
        if (isBackSpace == -92) {
            print("Backspace was pressed")
            //Reload Your data here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error: Use of unresolved identifier 'string'. What should I put there?

Comment: Do I just put `self.listTableView.reloadData()` where it says "//Reload your data here"?

Comment: Get update data from DB then call self.listTableView.reloadData() and  Please call self.listTableView.reloadData() when searchBar.text?.count == 0 it will solved your issue .

Answer (score 0):

The Bug here is that you call the filter method on your collection and assign it to the same collection, like so:

```
listOfExercises = listOfExercises?.filter("nameOfExercise CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!).sorted(byKeyPath: "nameOfExercise", ascending: true)
```

When you call the function the next time (i.e. when pressing backspace) you filter the new, filtered listOfExercises again. You need to either query realm directly

```
listOfExercises = realm.objects(Exercise.self).("nameOfExercise CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!)
```

Or, alternatively, save an instance of the original list in your class and query it.